# When call stored procedure in php, returns value =1 , but data don't insert in table

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I use mssql,
The procedure is in php. The stored procedure parameter is XML.

so..

```
$Conn = mssql_connect('servername','username','password');
$stmt = mssql_init('procedureName',$rCon);
  mssql_bind($stmt, '@XML1', $TEST_DATA, SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($stmt, '@XML2', $DATA2, SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($stmt, '@XML3', $DATA3, SQLVARCHAR);
  mssql_bind($stmt, '@XML4', $ERR_MSG, SQLVARCHAR, TRUE);

$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
```

I returned value = 1; 
does that mean TRUE? so i checked table! but, didn't insert.. 
why can't I insert? I can't guess.
 Isn't it bound properly?

procedure XML Mapping

```
<ROOT>
  <ROW>
    <SEQ>1</SEQ>
    <DATA>TEST</DATA>
  </ROW>
</ROOT>
```

Is it because of this? `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
When creating the XML format,
I used `saveXML ()`

```
$bRoot = new SimpleXMLElement('<ROOT/>');
        $bRow = $bRoot->addChild('ROW');
        $bRow->addChild('SEQ',$docu->docuNo);
        $bRow->addChild('DATA',"TEST");
        $TEST_DATA = $bRoot->saveXML();
          .
          .
          .
```

Really frustrating!

Comment: You will need to include the Stored Procedure code as there is no way to know what the return value of 1 means and what it is trying to do with your XML.

Comment: Also is good to include in the question the values for all four parameters for your stored procedure.